# Command to get list of all files that does not contain specific string but only from directories matching a name regex

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, grep

Directories-

- home/Modules/abc/iAmAFile
  Content of iAMAFile: *Random123*
- home/Modules/atoz/iAmAFile
  Content of iAMAFile: *Random123*
- home/Modules/23abc/iAmAFile/src
  Content of iAMAFile: *Random1*
- home/Modules/123abc/iAmAFile
  Content of iAMAFile: *Random3*
- home/Modules/123a/src/iAmAFile
  Content of iAMAFile: *Random1*

The output I am looking for is:

- home/Modules/23abc/src/iAmAFile  (Content is *Random1*)
- home/Modules/123abc/iAmAFile     (Content is *Random3*)

**Explanation**: These files do not contain *Random123* and are child of directory with abc on its name.

**home/Modules/123a/src/iAmAFile** does not qualify as although it does not have *Random123* in sub file **iAmAFile**, but the name of parent or pre-parent directory does not qualify as it does not contain *abc*.

The other two do not qualify as **iAmAFile** has the string *Random123*

The command I came up with is:

```
ls -F Modules/*abc | grep -r -L --include="iAmAFile" "Random123"
```

which gives a output

- home/Modules/23abc/src/iAmAFile
    (Content is *Random1*)
- home/Modules/123abc/iAmAFile**
       (Content is *Random3*)
- home/Modules/123a/src/iAmAFile.
     (Content is *Random1*)

It includes the directories that does not match the naming criteria.

Comment: Use `find` with options `-name`, `-type`, `-exec grep ...`

Comment: Thanks @Nic3500. How to use -exec grep? Can't understand much about it from man. What I came up with is `find . -maxdepth 1 -regex ".*abc$" | grep -r -L --include="iAmAFile" "Random123" `. But somehow the `grep` does not honor the `find`. The result contains all folders that do not have "Random123"

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting a combination of negative `grep` (`grep -v`) with positive `find` filter on the `path`.

```
grep -L "Random123" $(find . -type f -path "*abc*")
```

#### Explanation

##### `find . -type f -path "*abc*"`

List all the files under directory containing `abc` in path.

##### `grep -L "Random123" <files list>`

List all the files that do not contain `Random123` string. From `<files list>`.